# Why is the textblob module not being found in python databricks?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to use textblob to run sentiment analysis, but I am getting a "module not found" error when trying to run the analysis on a python/pyspark environment on databricks. I installed the library using `%sh pip install textblob` and then imported it using `import textblob`.

This is the result after the `%sh pip install textblob`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: textblob in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.15.3)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from textblob) (3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (4.46.1)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (2020.6.8)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob) (0.15.1)
```

Then I import it via `import textblob`

Then I run my sentiment function code block:

```
def get_sentiment(text):
    from textblob import TextBlob
    tweet = TextBlob(text)
    if tweet.sentiment.polarity < 0:
      sentiment = "negative"
    elif tweet.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        sentiment = "neutral"
    else:
        sentiment = "positive"
    return sentiment
  
# Define your function
getSentiment = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: get_sentiment(x), StringType())

# Apply the UDF using withColumn
tweets = tweets.withColumn('sentiment', getSentiment(col("tweet")))
```

The above code block returns this when running it:

```
tweets:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
data:string
id:string
ts:string
tweet:string
sentiment:string
```

Then I try and see the tweets pyspark dataframe

```
tweets.show()
```

and get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1463.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10189.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10189.0 (TID 10350, 10.81.233.238, executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 480, in main
    process()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 472, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 460, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 150, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 449, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 79, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: g(f(*a))
  File "<command-1260580097366150>", line 13, in <lambda>
  File "<command-1260580097366150>", line 2, in get_sentiment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob'
```

I am pretty new to pyspark and databricks so its kinda tough for me to try and diagnose that error message. Is this a textblob issue, or is it a pysaprk issue?

Comment: `%sh pip install textblob` installs library only on driver node. When you're using it in a udf, it's being executed on a worker, where there's no such library. In case of databricks, you need to add this library to your job / interactive cluster, this way databricks would install it on all the necessary nodes.

Comment: Thanks. I had to import the library via pypi in databricks and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import the library via pypi in databricks and assign the install to the specific notebook I was working in and using the library in.